# Why does an increase in LSTM units degrade my model's performance so drastically?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Last 2 months I've been trying different deep learning approaches to PV power forecasting. I built a dataset that contains 3 years (1095 days) worth of PV power output from 10 different arrays. I've encoded datetime information using sin and cos components for the months, days, hours and minutes. I've resampled my dataset to by in 15 minute resolution. I've used a sliding window to build my input tensor of the shape: (samples, timesteps, features). With all the additional weather data I've collected I have come to a grand total of 51 features. When I delete all samples that contain a NaN value (masking does not work with CuDNN LSTM). I am certain that these features contain valuable information that can be used to forecast PV power more accurately. So here is my problem:

I've gridsearched LSTM configurations and made many manual attempts, but completely against what appears to be common knowledge I keep arriving to the conclusion that less hidden units in the LSTM is better, and retuning sequences at the end of the LSTM stack improves the result. Here is the model I've come to accept works best:

```
initializer = keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.05)
bias = keras.initializers.Constant(0.1)

lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(Input(shape = (x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))

lstm.add(LSTM(units = 1, return_sequences = True))
# lstm.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
lstm.add(Flatten())
lstm.add(Dense(units = 100,  activation = 'linear',
               kernel_initializer = initializer,
               bias_initializer = bias))

lstm.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))

lstm.add(Dense(units = y_test.shape[1], activation = 'relu',
               kernel_initializer = initializer,
               bias_initializer = bias))

lstm.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
lstm.summary()
```

When i run this the summary looks like this:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 670, 1)            212       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 670)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 100)               67100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 67)                6767      
=================================================================
Total params: 74,079
Trainable params: 74,079
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The output shape of the first layer is 67 quarter hours (from 3:30 until 20:00 every day) for 10 days for a combined total of 670 input time-steps with 1 unit in the hidden layer. But this way the LSTM has only 212 parameters, and the Dense layers at the end over 70K. To me the impact of the LSTM is thereby marginalized.

Any training session with more than 3 units in the hidden layer ends up with the network learning to output the same vector regardless of the input. And in essence, not really learning anything. Do I need more data, or am I doing something else wrong here?